# my whirlpool side by side refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator

My whirlpool side by side refrigerator is not cold and freezer is cold but not making ice?  I have replaced the relay switch on compressor, I have taken the back off inside the freezer and the fan is working, I have taken the damper off and it is working, I have been told if fans are working the control panel is working, I have cleaned the coils (the best I can), the fan is working to cool compressor.  Don't know what else it could be, help! please

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What model is your refrigerator? How old is it? Is the only thing that's wrong the ice maker? If so, then there's a number of ways for an ice maker to fail.

Comment: Do you see frost build-up on evaporator coils?

Comment: How cold is the freezer?

Comment: Defrost timer, relay, or element....check those items.